# how to display items of an array returned from a function on html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, typescript

in the code posted below the method MousePosition which has coordianteFormat as an atttribute.
the createStringXY() returns a string encapsulates the longitude and latuitued, and they are comma separated. the latter function
keeps providing the long and lat values as the mouse moves.
the returned values from createStringXY() are to be displayed in the html tag

```
<div id="mouse-position"></div>
```

what i want to achieve is to display the value of the longitude and latitude separately in the html.
according to the documentation createStringXY returns an array:

```
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html#~CoordinateFormat
```

please let me know how to do it

**code**:

```
ngOnInit(){

var mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
  className: 'custom-mouse-position',
  coordinateFormat: createStringXY(7),
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
  // be placed within the map.
  target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
  undefinedHTML: '',//for what to be rendered when the mouse leaves map scope: values https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_control_MousePosition-MousePosition.html
});
```

}

**html**:

```
<div class="MousePosition">
  <div id="mouse-position"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use *ngFor loop , its look like your using angular so for angular you need to apply *ngFor loop in html (if data is coming in array) otherwise you can access data in html like that   {{data.lat}}

Comment: @Wajid would you please provide an example

Comment: Can you display array like ['1', '2', '3'] in html? If no - for what is all that information above?